# PHP: Upgrade to php 7.1.1 receiving this warning: A non well formed numeric value encountered in

Tags: php, joomla

I upgraded a Joomla site php from `5.*` to `7.1.1` and now I get this warning:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered in

Here is the part of the code:

```
foreach (JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->getMarks() as $mark)
        {
            var_dump($mark);
            $totalTime += $mark->time; //Error line here
            $totalMem  += (float) $mark->memory;
```

`var_dump` output:

> object(stdClass)#12 (6) { ["prefix"]=> string(11) "Application"
>   ["time"]=> string(16) "+75.977802276611" ["totalTime"]=>
>   float(75,977802276611) ["memory"]=> string(16) "+1.3794021606445"
>   ["totalMemory"]=> float(1,7153472900391) ["label"]=> string(9)
>   "afterLoad" }

So if I change `$totalTime += $mark->time;` to `$totalTime += strtotime($mark->time);`

I get this error:

> Warning: Division by zero in ...

Which line is:

```
'width' => round($mark->time / ($totalTime / 100), 4),
```

Comment: You'll need to remove the + and convert the strings to floats.

Comment: @aynber if I do that it will throw `A non well formed numeric value encountered in` in line `'width' => round($mark->time / ($totalTime / 100), 4),`

Comment: Do the same there as well.

Comment: Feeding `75,977802276611` to `strtotime` makes little sense. And because that fails, `$totalTime` is 0 afterwards, which is the explanantion for the “division by zero” error you get later on.

Comment: What is `float(75,977802276611)` anyway? Should use a `.` as decimal separator. Surprised to see that as the result of a var_dump, I am not aware that was taking any locale settings regarding number formatting into account …?

Comment: @misorude the question is why it is not failing in php 5.*? I don't know what exactly is because its modified from another developer. I am trying to update the site to latest php version

Comment: @aynber if I remove the `+` from `+=` as you suggested I guess that I change the logic of the code, and I don't want to do that. I just want to upgrade the php to the latest one. I don't want to mess the code that another developer built

Comment: _“the question is why it is not failing in php 5.*?”_ - probably because it ignored this, and applied some logic to somehow create a usable number out of that input silently … But what happens when you try `$totalTime += $mark->totalTime;` instead? According to your var_dump, that seems to be properly recognized as an actual float value already - and it seems to be essentially the same value as `$mark->time`, the latter just being a “formatted” version.

Comment: @misorude I did that and worked, thank you. Now I have to change all instances of $mark->time to $totalTime because its in other files too. I will get back if it wont work.

Comment: I meant remove the + from the string, though after testing, casting as float automatically does that.

Comment: I suggest you ask on the Joomla stack exchange site [joomla.se].